# How to create tagging for Items in a database with Asp.NET Core and Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, tags, many-to-many

Let's look at my tables that are used for the purpose of tagging.

I have:

```
Items
 - ItemsId
 - Name

Keywords
 - KeywordId
 - Keyword

Items_Kewyords
  - ItemsId
  - KeywordId
```

Now, using Asp.NET Core, should I include a method in Controller to add the items or should it be implemented in View. What are the recommended ways to do this?

I am binding my other values using

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Create ([Bind("Name,Blah,Blah")] Items item) 
{
_context.Add(item)
await _context.SaveChangesAsync(); 
}
```

Is there a way to bind the tags?

Comment: In general, I did not find the whole idea of using `Bind` very useful and a lot less flexible for many reasons. It was eventually much more praticle to simply use `Add(new Item{  item.OnlyWhatYouWantToAdd  })`

Comment: @NevilleNazerane Do you know any methods where I can get the keyword string from controller .Split them to list. Add keywords to keywords table if not exists, and (if exists) add keywords id to keyword_items table and items id to keyword_items table to create relationship.

Comment: as far as your remove bind, your controller will accept list of items too